# HTML5 Local Storage Data Display

Tags: html, cordova, local-storage

I am working with an app in Phonegap... SO in this App I am saving some values in local storage and is displaying it... For example .. when user enters his name and date of birth each of it is saved in seperate key values. When user presses a button called recall button all the saved values need to be displayed. Here Iam saving the firstname only and in next page I am retrieving it.. The problem is when I am retrieving it I am getting only the last saved name.

Suppose first user entered a name Aaron and saved the value.. then he entered Sandra and saved.. then he entered Dona then saved... and if retrieving means I am getting only the value Dona.. If I want to display all the three values how I need to programme.. I am giving the code I did.

```
<button onclick="save_data()" type="button">Save</button>
<input type="submit"  >
<button onclick="recall_data()" type="button">Recall</button>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function save_data(){
        var firstn = document.getElementById("fn");

window.localStorage.setItem('First Name', firstn.value);

        }
</script> 

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function recall_data(){

window.location = "recallpage.html";

        }
```

and in the recall page I did like this

```
<body onload="onLoad();">

function onLoad() {
    var text = "";
var section2 = document.getElementById("listing");
     for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
     var key = localStorage.key(i);
     var value = localStorage.getItem(key); 


text = localStorage.getItem(key)  + "<br>" ;


    }
   section2.innerHTML += text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jocheved what you are doing is window.localStorage.setItem('First Name', firstn.value); .. you are setting key FirstName with firstn value... and only one value can be set for that key.. in this type of occassions instead of saving values in localstorage save values in table.. so you can select each value according to name from the table...

sample code for creating table

```
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
 tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, data, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (data, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',[firstn,lastn,dayb,monb,yrb,middlen]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```
text = localStorage.getItem(key)  + "<br>" ;
```

To this:

```
text += localStorage.getItem(key)  + "<br>" ;
```

You are constantly overwriting `text` in the for-loop and because of that it will end up the last value in `localStorage`. Adding the `+=` will make it so all the keys in `localStorage` are concatenated together.

Another solution would be just moving `section2.innerHTML += text` inside the for-loop:

```
 for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    ...
    text = localStorage.getItem(key)  + "<br>" ;
    section2.innerHTML += text; 
}
```

Comment: and then you would probably want to change section2.innerHTML += text; to section2.innerHTML = text;

Comment: @Jocheved You don't have to. You can either use the solution above or you can move `section2.innerHTML += text;` inside the for-loop at the end.

Comment: Now... I am getting a value called Undefined in the first line and then the last saved value

Comment: @ Spencer....Now also same thing is happening... but one additional line 'Undefined' is coming... thta is the difference

Comment: @Jocheved Maybe you have localStorage items that are not defined? I wasn't able to see any problems [from this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdk66b9m/). Check and make sure `firstn.value` is defined.

Comment: Can you please check now ...http://jsfiddle.net/bdk66b9m/2/ why it is not showing the three values and only showing the last value... i give same key value to all

Comment: @Jocheved `localStorage.getItem('item1')` will always have the same value, there is no reason why it would change in the loop. You need to do `localStorage.getItem(key)` like [in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdk66b9m/3/). Note generally you don't want to use the same name for different items.